# Is it alright for an exhaust fan to vent into the loft?

Tags: attic, ventilation, exhaust-fan

I live in a rented property, when I moved in a new bathroom suite had been installed.

We however have had chronic condensation problems in the property.

when going into the loftspace I could not believe that the ventilation pipe is just venting into the loft itself.

Also the exhaust fan is approx 6 feet high from the bathrooms ceiling and there is a bend in the pipe of approx 60 degrees, and then after another foot or so, the fan sits.

I'm just enquiring if this is in anyway cited as good practice, or is the workmanship poor?

Answer (score 4):

Bad, bad, bad.

Mold will be in evidence shortly in the loft (attic), as we go into warmer weather.

The vent must run to the exterior, either through a gable wall or through the roof.  Its easier to properly down-slope to the gable wall (to eliminate any condensation in the vent pipe.

To reduce pipe condensation (either inside or outside of pipe), a jacket of insulation is suggested.  Also suggested is smooth walled pipe, gradual turns and no screw penetrations into the vent airspace.

Comment: +1 Even though it is agreed this is a terrible practice, it is apparently a quite common practice. The more I hear about it, the angrier I get. I imagine a special unpleasant place for people that do bad things because no one can easily see it.

Comment: Integrity is what you do when no one is looking.  I wish I could publish a bath where this happened.  I had to take down 3/4 of the ceiling (it wasn't discovered until the mold ate through the drywall) and of course, replaced the sodden insulation.

Answer (score 2):

The exhaust fan for the bathroom humidity should not empty out into interior space.  That defeats the purpose of it.  Most systems are installed with the fan in the hole cutout and then ducting to exhaust that hot humid air outside.